# Substitution a value in a SQL Select

Tags: sql, select, drop-down-menu

I have a co-worker with a problem I don't know if there is a solution to.

Here is gist of her code:

Select A, B, C
from
Xtable
Where values are (X, Y, Z);

The values of 'A' are shown in a drop-down list in Page Builder (coming from a Banner Database)

One of users wants to substitute a value of A to show something else.
For example, if A is Animal Type (like cat, dog, etc), B is Species, and C is Genus.
They don't want to see 'Cat'...they want to see 'Feline'.

There are other database users who use and want the value 'Cat'.

Question: How/Can we do the select..that populates a drop-down list and have it show 'Feline' when the value is 'Cat'?

never encountered this request in all my years of programming

Comment: What about ```CASE WHEN A = 'Cat' THEN 'Feline'...```

Comment: how do use use Case in a select ...
The banner table we are select from has about 200 values and a few fields
my example was 
Select A,B, C from X table where D=2.
and then we are population a select list with the values of A.
if I = Cat... they want Kitty to show in the list


does that explain it better

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mapping table which maps original values to the desired display labels like this:

```
Create Table mapping(ID INT, OriginalValue nvarchar(15), DisplayValue nvarchar(15));

INSERT INTO mapping VALUES(1,'Cat','Feline');
INSERT INTO mapping VALUES(2,'Dog','Canine');
```

and then join your original table with this maaping table.

```
SELECT A, B, C, M.DisplayValue
FROM Xtable
INNER JOIN MappingTable M ON Xtable.A = M.OriginalValue
WHERE Value in('X','Y','Z');
```

Comment: That would be cool if there were 3 values... instead of say 200
I just used 3 values as an example